# Angular routing exceptions handing in error handler

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-errorhandler

How to handle navigation errors in `ErrorHandler`?

I tried using the following condition to check whether `Error` object is of `NavigationError` but it says false.

```
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor() { }

  handleError(error: Error) {
if (error instanceof NavigationError) {
      //do something here, may be notify or redirect to error page.
    }
}
```

> How to handle router navigation errors in `ErrorHandler`? I don't want to add wildcard routing.

Will the above condition works if the type is correct? If so, against what type I should check?

Comment: And where you are doing that .....

Comment: @Antoniossss Updated question, I'm using Angular global error handler.

Comment: out of curiosity, why you don't want to add wildcard routing?

Comment: @deezg I had some difficulty in using child routing. But the main reason is if I can get the navigation error, instead of just redirecting, I can do almost anything like showing notification / logging.

Comment: Did you add it to providers?

Comment: @Antoniossss yes, Error handler works, but I need to check whether triggered error is of navigation. If I do `instanceof Error` it validates as `true`.

Comment: log errors to console so you will se what is passed to `handleError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@prajwal

try to use the next way to handle errors, it should works on 99.9% =):

```
import { Router, NavigationError } from '@angular/router';

 constructor( private router: Router) {
this.router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationError).subscribe(e => {
  console.log(`NAV ERROR -> ${e}`);
});
```

}

Result:

[image: The right relative path is ./home, but I have tried to go on ./home2]

Comment: this doesn't work with `rxjs 6`. Also, where to add this? In error handler or in app component?

Comment: He used injecter `Router` not errors handler, maybe that is the way to go

Comment: @Antoniossss But this method depends on a callback, which cannot be used in error handler.

Comment: @prajwal you can add this nav err event handling filter into a separate singleton service and share it on the `root` level. here you can read about it https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: why should I create a singleton service for this?

Comment: because such things as Error handlers, connection string managers and etc. should be created only once and they can be used by consumers globally. read articles about best practices, please. hope it would help you in your decisions

Answer (score 0):

The other answer was a good starting point, but did not work with Angular 13, this is what I came up with

```
readonly router$: Subscription;

constructor(private router: Router){

    this.router$ = this.router.events.pipe(
        filter((e) => e instanceof RouterEvent),
        filter((e) => e.constructor.name === 'NavigationError')
    ).subscribe((e: NavigationError) => {
        console.error(`Could not load URL "${e.url}" ${e.error}`);
    });
}
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.router$?.unsubscribe();
}
```